# "When would be convenient for you to meet?" VS "When it will be convenient for you?"

Tags: questions

I have to write a formal email to my manager for arranging a short meeting. 
What is the more formal and correct expression in this context:

> When would be convenient for you to meet?
>
> When it will be convenient for you?
>
> Please would you indicate a suitable time to meet?

---

**For instance, consider:**

Hi XXX,

My contract is almost over, I would like to arrange an appointment/short meeting to discuss about it.

When would be convenient for you to meet?

Thanks 
My name

Comment: As far as I know, using *would* is more polite than *will*.

Comment: "When it will be convenient?" is never correct, because we change the word order for questions in English.  You would have to say "When will it...?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When requesting

> When would it be convenient for you to meet?

is a polite, formal way to ask.

Less formal examples might be

> When will it be convenient for you to meet?
>   When might it be convenient to meet?
>   When could we meet?
>
> Please would you indicate a suitable time to meet ?